# I need to send an email to one email(test@gmail.com) when a Picklist value is updated to one value

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have a custom object Bank__c, Whenever a picklist Branch__c is updated to 'California' an email should be sent to test@gmail.com(just this address), that email contains related Branch_Id__c in the body.
I couldn't just create an Email template because Branch is not related to Contact.

Instead I created an Apex controller, VisualForce Component, Visualforce Email Template and a Process Builder.

An email is being sent when the field is updated, but the problem is with the Apex Controller

```
public class BankAutoEmails{
public Id BankId{get; set;}
public List<Bank__c> getBranch(){          
    List<Bank__c> bankList = new List<Bank__c>();       
        bankList = [Select Name, Branch_id__c
                    FROM Bank__c
                    WHERE Branch__c = 'California'];        
   return bankList;
}   
}
```

VF Comp:

```
<apex:component controller="BankAutoEmails" access="global" >
<apex:attribute name="bId" type="Id" description="Id of Bank" assignTo=
{!BankId}"/>
<html>
<body>
   <apex:repeat value="{!Branch}" var="b">
<tr>
      Branch Id: {!l.Branch_id__c}
</tr>
</apex:repeat><br/>    
</body>
</html>
</apex:component>
```

Process Builder:

```
Email Alert will be sent only when the Branch__c is updated to California
Email Alert has the To Address: test@gmail.com
```

The email Output is:

Email:

```
Branch Id: 12345
Branch Id: 67899
```

Instead I want one email for `12345` and another email for `67899`
It is giving me the list of all the records for which the Branch__c is California. As I am using List, I am getting this data. I think I need to use the `public string BankId{get; set;}` but don't know how to start with that. can someone help me with this, thanks.

Comment: **I couldn't just create an Email template because Branch is not related to Contact.** You could have created a [Cross object formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_creating_cross_object_advanced.htm&type=5) field and make use of it??

Comment: Thanks Arnold but I am not sending an email to contact, I am sending it to one outside email. So in email template it wouldn't populate the value even though I have a cross object formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to send it to one email, you don't need to use code. Just create an email alert and put the email address in the additional emails field. You can then use process builder to trigger the email when the picklist value is selected.

Comment: Yes, but the email body should have related Branch Id and Branch Name which I cannot do that in the Email Template, other than VF Email template.

Comment: What object are you using on the email alert? I think you are making this way too complicated.

Comment: I am using custom object Bank__c

Comment: The requirement is.....
Send an email to Test@example.com when `Branch__c = 'California' `...
`Subject: info`.....
`Body:
Your account is in Branch__c with Branch_id__c and Branch_Name__c`

Comment: So, make an email template with Bank__c merge fields {!Bank__c.Branch_id__c} and then make an email alert using the Bank__c object.

Comment: Ahh! got it @DanielHoechst! I don't need code at all, worked like a charm. As you said I was complicating this. I thought that email alert wouldn't pick the fields data. This was so so simple. Thank you so much Daniel, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a checkbox field, which sets to true whenever the Branch__c is updated to 'California' with the same Process Builder I was using before.

In my Process Builder
1st criteria: Ischanged(Picklist) AND Picklist = california
Action : Send Email Alert
Stop: Instead of Stop I selected Evaluate Next Criteria

2nd Criteria: No criteria Just update Records
Action: Update checkbox to True.

I modified my query in the Apex class to

```
List<Bank__c> bankList = new List<Bank__c>();       
    bankList = [Select Name, Branch_id__c
                FROM Bank__c
                WHERE Branch__c = 'California' AND checkbox = false];
```

Based on Order of execution an email was sent first then the checkbox is set to true.

Might not be a great idea code wise, but will work Logic wise. Hope this might help someone. Thanks.